# Use a variable as an index in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have created a layout using a simple WP loop and Im trying to randomise the images that display in the background of each post in the loop.

My method.

1. Create a function that contains an array of images that I can call from anywhere in the template.
2. Call the function for the array before the loop.
3. Use $i to get the each index in the array thus changing the image.

My array function ( a list of 30 images ):

```
function randompics(){
  $images = array(
   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/jobs_large/1.jpg', 
   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/jobs_large/2.jpg', 
   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/jobs_large/3.jpg', 
   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/jobs_large/4.jpg', 
   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/jobs_large/5.jpg' 
  );
  return $images;
}
```

My template. So I want the background URL to advance through the index of the array with each iteration.

```
<?php 
$pics = randompics();
$i = 0; 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post(); 
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="item-container" style="background: url(<?php echo $pics[$i]; ?>);"> 

    </div>
</div>

<?php 
        $i++;   
    endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION OF MY QUESTION.**
My question therefore is why is the background URL not working. The syntax is clearly wrong.

Comment: and the question would be what?

Comment: `<?php echo $pics[$i % count($pics)]; ?>`?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the loop except that you should check array item using "isset($pics[$i])" because if there are x number of images and x+n number of posts then you will get an exception (http://php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php) as there is no element at $pics[x].

Your "background" CSS property is wrong. Either use

```
background-image: url(YOUR IMAGE URL);
```

or

```
background:<background-color> <background-image> <background-repeat> <background-position>;
```

For example,

```
background:transparent url(YOUR IMAGE URL) no-repeat 0 0;
```